# Is there a need to create bi-directional relationship in Neo4j graph?

Tags: neo4j

For example,

```
iPhone productOf Apple
Apple  produces iPhone
```

I can create such two relations between the two nodes. I can query like this:

1) Which company's product is iPhone?

```
MATCH (Product {name:"iPhone"}) - [r:productOf] -> (company) return company
```

2) What products does Apple product?

```
MATCH (company {name:"Apple"}) - [r:produces] -> (products) return products
```

However, even without the 2nd relation "produces", I can still answer the 2nd question:

```
MATCH (products) - [r:productOf] -> (company {name:"Apple"}) return products
```

So it seems there is no need to create semantically equivalent relations between two nodes in data modelling. Is that true?

Comment: I suggest reading this article: [Modelling Data in Neo4j: Bidirectional Relationships](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is true.

Traversing a relationship in either direction (as you show in your question) is equally easy and efficient.

In addition, you can traverse a relationship without even specifying the directionality.